# retrieving EntryID for Checkbox item in Google Sheets Form not working

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms

I used the code from @contributorpw on this post [get Entry ID which is used to pre-populate fields (Items) in a Google Form URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46017170/get-entry-id-which-is-used-to-pre-populate-fields-items-in-a-google-form-url) and added the extended list of form types from @SourceFli (in same post).

I get the error message: "Exception: The parameters (String) don't match the method signature for FormApp.CheckboxItem.createResponse".  That checkbox has only 1 option: "yes".

The rest of all my form items are only TEXT items and work fine.

```
function getPreFillEntriesMap(){
  var ssOrder = SpreadsheetApp.openById(ORDER_SPREADSHEET_ID);
  var orderFormUrl = ssOrder.getFormUrl();
  var orderForm = FormApp.openByUrl(orderFormUrl);

  var form = orderForm;
//  var form = FormApp.openById(id);
  var items = form.getItems();
  var newFormResponse = form.createResponse();
  var itms = [];
  for(var i = 0; i < items.length; i++){
    var response = getDefaultItemResponse_(items[i]);
    if(response){
      newFormResponse.withItemResponse(response);
      itms.push({
        id: items[i].getId(),
        entry: null,
        title: items[i].getTitle(),
        type: "" + items[i].getType()
      });
    }
  }

  var ens = newFormResponse.toPrefilledUrl().split("&entry.").map(function(s){
    return s.split("=")[0];
  });
  ens.shift();

  return Logger.log(itms.map(function(r, i){
    r.entry = this[i];
    return r;
  }, ens));

}


function getDefaultItemResponse_(item){
  switch(item.getType()){
    case FormApp.ItemType.TEXT:
      return item.asTextItem().createResponse("1");
      break;
    case FormApp.ItemType.MULTIPLE_CHOICE:
      return item.asMultipleChoiceItem()
        .createResponse(item.asMultipleChoiceItem().getChoices()[0].getValue());
      break;
    case FormApp.ItemType.CHECKBOX:
      return item.asCheckboxItem()
        .createResponse(item.asCheckboxItem().getChoices()[0].getValue());
      break;
    case FormApp.ItemType.DATETIME:
      return item.asDateTimeItem()
        .createResponse(new Date());
      break;
    case FormApp.ItemType.DATE:
      return item.asDateItem()
        .createResponse(new Date());
      break;
    case FormApp.ItemType.LIST:
      return item.asListItem()
        .createResponse(item.asListItem().getChoices()[0].getValue());
      break;
    case FormApp.ItemType.PARAGRAPH_TEXT:
      return item.asParagraphTextItem()
        .createResponse(item.asParagraphTextItem().createResponse("some paragraph"));
      break;
    case FormApp.ItemType.CHECKBOX_GRID:
      return item.asCheckboxGridItem()
        .createResponse(item.asCheckboxGridItem().createResponse([item.asGridItem().getColumns[0], item.asGridItem().getRows[0]]));
      break;
    case FormApp.ItemType.DURATION:
      return item.asDurationItem()
        .createResponse(item.asDurationItem().createResponse(2, 20, 20));
      break;
    case FormApp.ItemType.GRID:
      return item.asGridItem()
        .createResponse(item.asGridItem().createResponse([item.asGridItem().getColumns[0], item.asGridItem().getRows[0]]));
      break;
   case FormApp.ItemType.SCALE:
      return item.asScaleItem()
        .createResponse(item.asScaleItem().createResponse(1));
      break;
   case FormApp.ItemType.TIME:
      return item.asTimeItem()
        .createResponse(item.asTimeItem().createResponse(1, 1));
      break;
    default:
      return undefined; 
  } 
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`response` of `createResponse(responses)` of Class CheckboxItem is `String[]`. In your script, the string is used. I thought that this might be the reason of your issue. So how about the following modification?

#### From:

```
return item.asCheckboxItem()
        .createResponse(item.asCheckboxItem().getChoices()[0].getValue());
```

#### To:

```
return item.asCheckboxItem()
        .createResponse([item.asCheckboxItem().getChoices()[0].getValue()]);
```

#### Reference:

- [createResponse(responses)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/checkbox-item#createResponse(String))

Comment: Thanks again once more @Tanaike !!